# How to purl each chunks in .Rmd file to multiple .R files using Knitr

Tags: r, knitr

We can purl a .Rmd file to a  .R file, But how to  purl  each chunks in .Rmd  file to separate .R files named by the tag of chunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have the following .Rmd document called "test.Rmd":

````
This is a test.

```{r chunk1}
1:4
```

This is a further test.

```{r chunk2}
5:6
```
````

If `purl`-ed, you get the following:

```
## ----chunk1--------------------------------------------------------------
1:4


## ----chunk2--------------------------------------------------------------
5:6
```

You can put this instead into separate files by first using `purl`, using the `read_chunk` function, and then just writing each chunk to a separate file:

```
library("knitr")
p <- purl("test.Rmd")
read_chunk(p)
chunks <- knitr:::knit_code$get()
invisible(mapply(function(chunk, name) {
    writeLines(c(paste0("## ----",name,"----"), chunk), paste0("chunk-",name,".R"))
}, chunks, names(chunks)))
unlink(p) # delete the original purl script
knitr:::knit_code$restore() # remove chunks from current knitr session
```

This produces a file for each chunk that is named `"chunk-chunk1.R"`, `"chunk-chunk2.R"`, etc. containing just the code for that chunk.

Comment: This also worked for .Rnw file and Included sub file, really nice!

Comment: @BingweiTian If this answer worked for you, consider up voting it and marking it as accepted by clicking the "check mark" to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for kind reminding, I have checked the **Check mark**, but still donot have enough reputation to vote up.