# With knitr, preserve chunk options when purling chunks into separate files

Tags: r, knitr, rnw

For teaching purposes, I would like to `purl` the chunks of my `.Rnw` file into separate files. This answer explains how to do it:

[How to purl each chunks in .Rmd file to multiple .R files using Knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800604/how-to-purl-each-chunks-in-rmd-file-to-multiple-r-files-using-knitr)

BUT the method does not preserve the chunk options. Since the chunks I have produce plots, it's important to preserve the `fig.width` and `fig.height` options. Ideally I would like a chunk that looks like this:

```
<<plot, fig.width = 3, fig.height = 5, outwidth = '.75\\textwidth'>>=
plot (1,1)
@
```

to become a file named `plot.R` that looks like this:

```
#+ fig.width = 3, fig.height = 5
plot (1,1)
```

That is, turn the chunk options `fig.width` and `fig.height` into a format that will be recognized by `spin()`, as `purl()` does, and get rid of the chunk options that are irrelevant, or create problems for `spin()` into Word, such as `out.width`. All in the spirit of creating code files that are user-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer you refer to doesn't copy the header line from the results of `purl`, you lose everything besides the chunk name. While you could adapt it to paste in the headers, it's actually not hard to build a function to parse the output of `purl`—much easier than trying to parse a `Rmd` or `Rnw` document, anyway, and easier than sorting out exactly how `knitr` does so.

```
purl_chunks <- function(input_file){
  purled <- knitr::purl(input_file)    # purl original file; save name to variable
  lines <- readLines(purled)    # read purled file into a character vector of lines
  starts <- grep('^## ----.*-+', lines)    # use grep to find header row indices
  stops <- c(starts[-1] - 1L, length(lines))   # end row indices
  # extract chunk names from headers
  names <- sub('^## ----([^-]([^,=]*[^,=-])*)[,-][^=].*', '\\1', lines[starts])
  names <- ifelse(names == lines[starts], '', paste0('_', names)) # clean if no chunk name
  # make nice file names with chunk number and name (if exists)
  file_names <- paste0('chunk_', seq_along(starts), names, '.R')
  for(chunk in seq_along(starts)){    # loop over header rows
    # save the lines in the chunk to a file
    writeLines(lines[starts[chunk]:stops[chunk]], con = file_names[chunk])
  }
  unlink(purled)    # delete purled file of entire document
}
```

A couple notes:

- While the regex works for what I've thrown at it, it may yet be fallible. Tested:

  - no chunk name
  - no name but chunk settings
  - name with hyphens
  - single character names
  - names with spaces, including after (before the comma/brace)
- As `.Rnw` and `.Rmd` files both `purl` the same, it works for either.
- It uses the default setting (`1L`) for `purl`'s `documentation` parameter. `0L` wouldn't have chunk headers and is thus pointless here anyway, but it would handle `2L` (which would include text chunks as `roxygen` comments) stupidly. It could be rebuilt for such, though, if you wanted text chunks with the following code chunk.
- While the output header lines of `purl` don't look exactly like your example above (they start with `## ----` and are filled with hyphens), they `spin` properly; results obey chunk options.

Comment: Amazing, works like a charm. Thanks a million. This is what I wish I knew how to do... I will study it and learn.